# Linux Iptables Routing

Tags: windows, linux, routing, centos, iptables

I need help with a problem. My setup is:

1. CentOS (Router)
   eth1 18.0.168.1 255.255.248.0
   eth2 145.165.34.1 255.255.254.0
2. Windows Server 2008
   18.0.168.2

My problem is from the Windows machine, I can't get to the 145.165.34.0/23 network. I will be using that network for DHCP later.

Things I have tried which I am sure I am not doing it correctly are iptables forwarding, and ip route. For now I took those settings out.

Right now, 18.0.168.2 (Windows) can ping 18.0.168.1 (CentOS), but not 145.165.34.1.

Thanks if you can help.

```
[kyle@router ~]$ ip route list
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15  metric 1 
145.165.34.0/23 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 145.165.34.1  metric 1 
18.0.168.0/21 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 18.0.168.1  metric 1 
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0  proto static
```

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 13 ...08 00 27 85 23 ea ...... Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter #2
 10 ...08 00 27 a2 2c 54 ...... Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter
  1 ........................... Software Loopback Interface 1
 11 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  isatap.{52742097-8F78-484C-BF9E-D51D32CB1CA2}
 12 ...02 00 54 55 4e 01 ...... Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 14 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  isatap.{6DC0C149-3D90-43A0-952F-64C4C749F785}
 15 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  6TO4 Adapter
===========================================================================
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       18.0.168.1       18.0.168.2    266
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        10.0.2.15     10
         10.0.2.0    255.255.255.0         On-link         10.0.2.15    266
        10.0.2.15  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.2.15    266
       10.0.2.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.2.15    266
       18.0.168.0    255.255.248.0         On-link        18.0.168.2    266
       18.0.168.2  255.255.255.255         On-link        18.0.168.2    266
     18.0.175.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        18.0.168.2    266
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link        18.0.168.2    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         10.0.2.15    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        18.0.168.2    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.2.15    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       18.0.168.1  Default
===========================================================================
IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
 15   1110 ::/0                     2002:c058:6301::c058:6301
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 12     18 2001::/32                On-link
 12    266 2001:0:4137:9e76:2810:2820:f5ff:fdf0/128
                                    On-link
 15   1010 2002::/16                On-link
 15    266 2002:1200:a802::1200:a802/128
                                    On-link
 13    266 fe80::/64                On-link
 10    266 fe80::/64                On-link
 12    266 fe80::/64                On-link
 10    266 fe80::5d8:1b7d:9d92:8306/128
                                    On-link
 12    266 fe80::2810:2820:f5ff:fdf0/128
                                    On-link
 13    266 fe80::70c3:f7f:15fe:8c38/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 12    266 ff00::/8                 On-link
 13    266 ff00::/8                 On-link
 10    266 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
C:\Users\Administrator>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the question, it looks like IP forwarding is not enabled.

To enable forwarding, edit the appropriate line in `/etc/sysctl.conf` like this:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

You can enable it immediately for testing like this (as root):

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

If this doesn't solve the problem, please include the routing table and iptables rules from  your linux server, and the routing table on the windows server

**EDIT**

You need to delete this route in Windows

```
0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        10.0.2.15     10
```

Windows will choose the route with the lowest metric first, and that default is overriding the other default.

Comment: That actually isn't my problem. I already edited /etc/sysctl.conf. I forgot to mention it. Thanks though.

Comment: Please include the routing table and iptables rules from the linux server, as well as the routing table from the windows server

Comment: What gateway do you have configured in the Windows Box?

Comment: I updated with the routing table. And the iptables rules are default. I even had them flushed for testing but didn't save.

Comment: My gateway is 18.0.168.1 which is one of the Linux box's ip addresses

Comment: @leeman24, please see my edit

Comment: Thank you for your help. I forgot to mention I am using virtual machines and am using that 10. network for the internet.